# Extract only the latest one (by date) from a json/dict using Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following dict http://uberlandia.com/papodebuteco/api/get_tag_posts/?tag_slug=uberlandiahome and I would like to extract only the latest one by date. Using python.

```
def get_posts(self):
r = requests.get('http://uberlandia.com/papodebuteco/api/get_tag_posts/?tag_slug=uberlandiahome',)
if r.ok:
    data = json.loads(r.content.encode('UTF-8'))
    for post in data['posts']:
        print data['posts'] # If it was django I could do .latest(), but it's not.
        print "==================================================="
        title = post['title']
        url = u'%s' % post['url'] 
        print post['attachments'][0]['images']['full']['url']
        print url
        print u'%s'% post['date']
        #dict = {'featured_post' : {'title' : title, 'url':url}}
else:pass
```

How can I return the latest post by date from this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy with max and a lambda function:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

latest = max(data['posts'], key=lambda x: parse(x['date']))
```

Answer (score -3):

the max function takes a key parameter! so you can do something like this:

```
def keyfunction(v):
    return parsedate(v["date"])

latest=max(yourdict["posts"],key=keyfunction))
```

the key parameter is real useful, and exists on a lot of builtin functions such as min, max, and sort.

Comment: could someone explain why this has 3 downvotes even though it's exactly the same as the accepted answer?